# How to expose HDFS in one cluster and access it with DataTap in another cluster/tenant?

Tags: bluedata, hpe-container-platform, ezmeral

I have created a 6.3x Cloudera cluster inside HPE Container Platform.

I would like to expose the HDFS so that it can be accessed via DataTap on other HPE Container Platform clusters for basic demonstration purposes (no HA or security required).

My cluster node info looks like this:

[image]

I understand that I need to expose port *8020* on the primary node - how can I do that?

Comment: @Downvoters/Closers - please add a comment to say why you think this question is inappropriate.  It's difficult to make improvements without knowing what is wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a cluster service, selecting the primary node:

[image]

You will see the new cluster service in the node info screen:

[image]

You can then create the DataTap using the hostname and port from the previous screen:

[image]

If you select the DataTap, you should be able to see the `/tmp` and `/user` folders:

[image]

---

Note this answer does *NOT* consider:

- [Kerberos Security](http://docs.bluedata.com/51_hdfs-datatap-kerberos-security)
- [Cross Realm Authentication](http://docs.bluedata.com/51_hdfs-datatap-cross-realm-kerberos-authentication)
- [Transparent Data Encryption](http://docs.bluedata.com/51_hdfs-datatap-tde-configuration)
- [Wire Encryption](http://docs.bluedata.com/51_hdfs-datatap-tde-configuration)
- [User Proxy](http://docs.bluedata.com/51_hdfs-datatap-tde-configuration)
- [User Passthrough](http://docs.bluedata.com/51_sample-hdfs-passthough-datatap)